# Access data in uncommon JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I need to access a spefic content of a JSON Object in JS, here's an example:

```
 _isEditedMessage: false,
  _message: 
   Message {
     _messageId: 0000,
     _from: 
      User {
        _id: 0000000,
        _firstName: 'bbbb',
        _lastName: null,
        _username: 'aaaa' },
     _date: 1474571521,
     _chat: 
      Chat {
        _id: 000000,
        _type: 'private',
        _title: null,
        _username: 'aaaa',
        _firstName: 'bbbb',
        _lastName: null },
     _forwardFrom: null,
```

I need to access the first name from `_firstName` no matter if its from User or Chat. I know I can access _isEditedMessage by using `$._isEditedMessage`.
I would like to have an output of `bbbb`

Comment: try `($._message._chat._firstName || $._message._from._firstName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JS object starts with `$` then it would be

```
console.log($._message._from._firstName || $._message._chat._firstName);
```